# Watermark specific page in PDF iTextSharp

Tags: itext, watermark

I create the PDF dynamically based on the custom object data and water mark all pages in the PDF using iTextSharp 5.5.10.0 as shown in the code below.

**Question:** How can I watermark one or more page based on the criteria in the for loop? Custom object data has a boolean flag which indicates whether the pdf page could be watermarked?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using (MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Document document = new Document())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream))
                    {
                        HeaderFooter headerfooter = new HeaderFooter();
                        headerfooter.watermarkpage = WaterMarkPage;
                        headerfooter.includefooter = IncludeFooter;
                        writer.PageEvent = headerfooter;
                        writer.CloseStream = false;
                        document.Open();
                        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                            foreach (TestResult testresultdata in testresults)
                            {
                                document.Add(PopulateData(testresultdata, reporttitle, includesponsordata));
                                // Move to next page
                                document.NewPage();
                            } // end foreach Order
                        document.Close();
                    } // end writer
                } // end document
          }
```

Comment: Your code is an example how not to merge and watermark PDFs. Use `PdfCopy` and page stamps, and use the page stamp only for pages to watermark..

Comment: Thanks @mkl for your suggestion